# SQL Server: select only items that exist in nested table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, subquery

I am using the following query to select a list of currencies from one table and get the corresponding exchange rates from another table which works well so far.

Can someone here tell me how I have to change this so that it only selects currencies that exist in both tables, i.e. which have an exchange rate available in table E (`C.currencyCode = E.from_currency`) ?

```
SELECT      C.currency,
            C.currencyCode,
            (
                SELECT      E.exchange_rate AS exchangeRate
                FROM        Exchange_Rates E
                WHERE       E.from_currency = C.currencyCode
                AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
                FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        Currencies C
ORDER BY    C.sortID, C.currency
FOR XML PATH('currencies'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give this a try?

```
SELECT      C.currency,
            C.currencyCode,
            (
                SELECT      E.exchange_rate AS exchangeRate
                FROM        Exchange_Rates E
                WHERE       E.from_currency = C.currencyCode
                AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
                FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        Currencies C
        JOIN Exchange_Rates E ON C.currencyCode = E.from_currency
ORDER BY    C.sortID, C.currency
FOR XML PATH('currencies'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - let me check.

Comment: This works great - thanks for the quick help ! I will accept as soon as I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      C.currency,
            C.currencyCode,
            (
                SELECT      E.exchange_rate AS exchangeRate
                FROM        Exchange_Rates E
                WHERE       E.from_currency = C.currencyCode
                AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
                FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        Currencies C
        INNER JOIN (Select MIN(exchange_rate),
        from_currency 
            from Exchange_Rates
            GROUP BY from_currency )E ON C.currencyCode = E.from_currency
ORDER BY    C.sortID, C.currency
FOR XML PATH('currencies'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```